# PHP How to shoot an email with an attched table?

Tags: php, mysql, email, attachment

I use `i-page` as a hosting company. I have a mySQL database. How can i shoot an email with an attached table? Let's say i have connected to my database:

```
$link = mysql_connect('www.....com', 'login', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db('rates', $link); 

// Now how do i SELECT table1??
// Do i create a variable $table = SELECT...
// Then how to attach it to an email and send the email?
```

Comment: +1 for 'How to shoot an email'.LOL

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and Let's make sure the the days of that email are numbered.

Comment: Thank you Very good example... The problem is that the table that i am sending is not on the webpage..it is in the database...so it means that i would have to create a temporary table on the webpage and populate it with the values, and only the can i send it...is that right?